# Problems with opening html

Tags: python, html, python-webbrowser

This must be the most weird and confusing problem I've ever seen. So I've been trying to open an html file with python using the:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab()
```

method, at first it worked as intended but then problems started to appear. When I ran the program the file would open, but after 1 second it would close. This would always happen when I ran the program with VS code but when I ran the python program in IDLE (v3.10.0) the program ran just fine. I'm out of my depth here and I have no idea what could be causing this problem.

```
def visit_website():
    print('Would you like to visit our website ?')
    def_a=input()
    if def_a=='yes' or def_a=='Yes' or def_a=='ok' or def_a=='Ok' or def_a=='OK':
         webbrowser.open_new_tab('demofile.html')
```

Comment: Is there any logs / output in console=

Comment: BTW you can simplify that `if` to `if def_a.lower() in ('yes', 'ok'):`

Comment: ??? I don't understand what you mean